# How to use Android predefined constants for binding data in xml layout file

Tags: android, android-databinding

Android provided new concept of showing data on UI via data binding. I tried implementing it on one of my application. While implementing Lambda expression as a click handler of my button, I required a constant i.e.View.VISIBLE for comparing it in my expression. But when I write below code:

```
android:onClick="@{(activity_main)-> activity_main.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? eventHandler.eventHandlerViaListenerBinding(true) : eventHandler.eventHandlerViaListenerBinding(false)}"
```

It is giving me an error:

> Error:(57, 83) Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. View is missing it

My question is how can I import constants in the xml?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your data tag add this.

```
<import type="android.view.View" />
```

or Just upate the build.gradle of the library to enable databinding as well as in the main project:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```